# How do I compare the result of a function to values in a list box to determine which form to open on start up?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to employ a basic level of security to my Access db.

I have a list of valid users and want to compare them to user name from advapi32.dll.

The code below is where I've got to with my AutoExec macro:

```
Function UserCompare()

Dim c As Control
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Boolean

DoCmd.OpenForm ("Users_Form")

Set c = Forms!Users_Form!lst_Users

For i = 0 To c.lst_Users.ListCount - 1
    If c.lst_Users.Column(0, i) = ThisUserName() Then
        y = True
    End If
Next i

If y = True Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("Login Screen - Authorised")
    Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("Login Screen - Unauthorised")
End If

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Users_Form", acSaveNo

End Function
```

This is resulting in a run-time error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,
Chas

Comment: In which row do you receive this error?

Comment: A list box is a weird place to store a list of users. You usually use a table for this. Furthermore, this is all pseudosecurity, what happens when a user enters using the bypass key? Or disables VBA altogether?

Comment: A list box in a form was used as a potential workaround.  The underlying list of users sit in a query.  Security is probably too strong a word here, what I've really after is just a detterent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set c = Forms!Users_Form!lst_Users

For i = 0 To c.ListCount - 1
    If c.Column(0, i) = ThisUserName() Then
        y = True
    End If
Next i
```